# How to allow a domain name in iptables?

Tags: linux, time, firewall, iptables

I have a linux server that gets an time offset for some strange reason

I set up cron job to run and update the time using the following command

```
/usr/sbin/ntpdate pool.ntp.org
```

The problem is the command would not run because I have a firewall (iptables)

I have always use IP to allow traffic in my network:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -i eth0 -s 11.11.11.11 --dport 5060 -j ACCEPT
```

I would like to know how to do it using a domain name in this case would be `pool.ntp.org`

Or maybe someone could tell me a better way to keep the clocks in sync

Please advice

Comment: No need to use cron. Use ntpd, it runs in the background and keeps your clocks in sync continuously.

Comment: It's not a good idea (IHMO) even if it's possible. You don't want to setup your firewall to make a dns lookup each time your rule matches (this is what i call "overkill"). And keep in mind that your firewall is relying on a service which is not known as secure. ;)

Comment: Please suggest an alternative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, iptables is setup to restrict incoming TCP and UDP connections initiated by remote hosts to the server except as needed.  But, all outgoing TCP and UDP connections initiated by the server to remote hosts are allowed, and state is kept so that replies are allowed back in, like so:

```
# Allow TCP/UDP connections out. Keep state so conns out are allowed back in.
iptables -A INPUT  -p tcp -m state --state ESTABLISHED     -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT  -p udp -m state --state ESTABLISHED     -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

If your iptables is setup like so, it will allow ntpdate to make an outgoing connection to pool.ntp.org, and it will allow the reply back in.  And, you can still block down incoming connections to the server initiated by other hosts.